# Tikz Pgfplots: request code tweak to adjust spacing & ticks on Cartesian plane with grid lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

With some borrowed code, I've created a 2 column (enumerated) 4 question mwe worksheet which asks students to find the solution to a system of equations by graphing.

The current code IMHO renders the tic labels in too large and too dark a font creating a crowded look:

[image]

The desired rendering is something like this (without the plotted line and "A" "B" labels):

[image]

4 questions if you would be so kind:

1. Please teach me the code line that controls **font size & color** of tic mark labels and suggest an improvement
2. Which line controls the **spacing between each horizontal / vertical** grid lines?
3. Since only 4 graphs appear per page of this worksheet, can the **size** of the blank cartesian plane **be increased** while **still fitting on a single page**?
4. In the full version of my code, I inserted a ** `\newpage` that was ignored**. What command should I use to force new page?

Many thanks for taking time to assist me!

mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}
\settasks{
%  after-item-skip=5em,
%  after-skip=2cm,
  label-width=2em,
  item-indent=3em,
  label=(\arabic*),
  column-sep=2em,
 }
 \pagestyle{head}
\header{\textbf{Algebra II: Quadratic Systems}}
{}
{ 04/17/23} 
\begin{document}

\textbf {SET A: Solve each system by graphing.}

\begin{tasks}(2)
%Prob #1
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-5, y=-2x-9}$\\
\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xmin=-10,xmax=10,
            ymin=-10,ymax=10,
            xlabel=$x$,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:1,0)},
            yshift=1.8em,
            anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$,
            every axis y label/.style={at={(yticklabel cs:1,0)},
            xshift=2.7em,yshift=0.2em,
            anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, xtick style={yshift=-0.5ex},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, ytick style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            minor tick num=1,
            minor tick length=0.5ex,
            minor x tick style={yshift=0.25ex}, minor y tick style={xshift=0.25ex},
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%Prob #2
  \task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{y=2(x+4)^2-3, y=x+7}$\\
\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xmin=-10,xmax=10,
            ymin=-10,ymax=10,
            xlabel=$x$,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:1,0)},
            yshift=1.8em,
            anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$,
            every axis y label/.style={at={(yticklabel cs:1,0)},
            xshift=2.7em,yshift=0.2em,
            anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, xtick style={yshift=-0.5ex},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, ytick style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            minor tick num=1,
            minor tick length=0.5ex,
            minor x tick style={yshift=0.25ex}, minor y tick style={xshift=0.25ex},
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%Prob #3
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*
{y=2(x-3)^2+1, 2x+y=11}$\\
\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xmin=-10,xmax=10,
            ymin=-10,ymax=10,
            xlabel=$x$,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:1,0)},
            yshift=1.8em,
            anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$,
            every axis y label/.style={at={(yticklabel cs:1,0)},
            xshift=2.7em,yshift=0.2em,
            anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, xtick style={yshift=-0.5ex},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, ytick style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            minor tick num=1,
            minor tick length=0.5ex,
            minor x tick style={yshift=0.25ex}, minor y tick style={xshift=0.25ex},
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%Prob #4
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*
{y=\frac{1}{2}(x-4)^2-3, y=2x-11}$\\
\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xmin=-10,xmax=10,
            ymin=-10,ymax=10,
            xlabel=$x$,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:1,0)},
            yshift=1.8em,
            anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$,
            every axis y label/.style={at={(yticklabel cs:1,0)},
            xshift=2.7em,yshift=0.2em,
            anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, xtick style={yshift=-0.5ex},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, ytick style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            minor tick num=1,
            minor tick length=0.5ex,
            minor x tick style={yshift=0.25ex}, minor y tick style={xshift=0.25ex},
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
%Problems 5 -8 on 2nd page
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you look into the [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) where all options are explained in detail. I think this will make it easier for you to understand how to style ticks or how to set the several options for grids, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For learn `pgfplots` you should read package documentation: Manual for Package pgfplots and see answers here on site and collection of examples on [PGFplots.net](https://pgfplots.net/filling-plots/)
- If you will stuck in your efort, of course ask for help here on site ...
- Following suggestion is similar to @Jasper Habicht answer, differences in a wee bit shorter code for axis settings.
- MWE is focused only on drawing only image.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=cyan!50, inner sep=1pt},
            xmin=-10,   xmax=10,          
            ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2,
            minor tick num=1,
            tick align=outside,
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice choice of (a different set of) options!

Comment: @JasperHabicht, thank you for nice words. Your answer is interesting too (+1).

Comment: @Zarko  Please know how much I appreciate your incredibly helpful solution. Your mwe is precisely the solution for my student worksheets / tests. For old guys like me who are trying to learn a new trick, generous people like you are simply amazing. Learning a little LaTeX is one of the most difficult challenges in my long teaching career. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer to your several questions (and actually, on this site it is always better to ask one question at a time), but let me give you some hints:

- You can use the option `axis equal` to have the same distances of the *x* and *y* ticks. You can control the distance of the grid lines using different ways, but considering the code example you have, it will be the `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` options as well as the `width` and `height` options. Using the `width` and `height` options, you can also control the actual size of the plot which will help you to place as many plots on one page.
- The font color and size of the ticks can be controlled using the `xticklabel style` and the `yticklabel style` options.
- I removed the `minor tick` settings from your example, because in the picture you show, such minor ticks are not used.
- If you want to use the same set of options over and over again, it might be helpful to create your custom `/.style`.

The above in one MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{
    my axis format/.style={
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={
            -stealth,
            shorten >=-3mm
        },
        axis equal,
        xmin=-8, xmax=8,
        ymin=-8, ymax=8,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        grid=both,
        grid style={
            draw=gray!25
        },
        xtick={-10,-9,...,10}, 
        xtick style={
            yshift=-0.5ex, 
        },
        xticklabel style={
            font=\scriptsize\color{blue}
        },
        ytick={-10,-9,...,10}, 
        ytick style={
            xshift=-0.5ex
        },
        yticklabel style={
            font=\scriptsize\color{blue}
        },
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis format
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't thank you enough for being such a patient teacher! I spent a couple of hours perusing the manual and looking at youtube videos without success. So I really appreciate your response. Given that all I'm trying to accomplish is the creation of blank coordinate planes that my students can use to hand graph, is there a more efficient coding approach that you can recommend?

Comment: In @Zarko code above, is it ok to increase vertical & horizontal tic distance by inserting ```[scale = 1.25]``` after ```\begin{tikzpicture}```? I ask because I couldn't figure out the proper syntax & placement for inserting ```height``` and ```width``` commands in Zarko's code.

Comment: @SiuslawMath You could create custom styles or even custom macros to avoid repetition of the code. I created a style above `my axis style` which you can use for several plots. To change things for single plots, just add the other options after using `my axis style`. As for scaling: I think that it might be a good idea to use `height` and `width`, since for example `height=10cm` would generate a plot that is 10cm hight. Because you said that you want to place mulitple plots on one page, this might help you with scaling. But yes, you could also use the `scale` option.