# x,y graph with labeled point

Tags: pgfplots, labels, ticks

New to graphing on latex. But I started something based on what I was seeing.

Current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-10, xmax=10,
    ymin=-10, ymax=10,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top=true,
    domain=0:1,
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output I get:

[image]

What I want (to control the grid... like going from -10 to 10 with increment by 1 or 2. Also to be able to graph points and to label it.

[image]

I saw how to graph points, but I needed to have a line first. With the line 2x it would work, but if I removed \addplot {2*x};(it doesn't work).

```
\addplot {2*x};
    \node[label={180:{(2,5)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:2,5) {};
    \node[label={180:{(-4,-3)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:-4,-3) {};
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683273/47927, but it is a bit unclear to me what exactly is your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=200mm, scale=0.9,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south east},
    grid=both,
    grid style={draw=gray!25},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, text=cyan!50, inner sep=1pt},
    xmin=-10,   xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,   ymax=10,
    xtick distance=1,
    ytick distance=1,
    tick align=outside,
%
    nodes near coords style={anchor=west, font=\footnotesize},
    mark size=2pt, only marks
        ]
\addplot +[visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Name}\as\name},   % <---
           nodes near coords = {$\name$},                             % <---
          ] table[x=X,y=Y] {  X   Y   Name    
        
                           -6   3   (-6,-3)
                           -4  -3   (-4,-3)
                            2   5   (2,5)
                            7  -2   (7,-2)
                            };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]